# How can I run apps inside an Intel SGX enclave on the Windows

Tags: python, azure, clang, sgx, confidential

everyone.
I have created a DCsv3 virtual machine in Azure on Windows.
How can I run the application from inside an Intel SGX enclave?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load an application into Intel SGX enclave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42786731/load-an-application-into-intel-sgx-enclave)

Comment: [Getting Started with Intel® Software Guard Extensions SDK for Microsoft* Windows* OS](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/getting-started-with-sgx-sdk-for-windows.html)